# Angular2 Pipe to convert currency

Tags: angular, filter, pipe, currency

I have created a method to convert currency using a api, which looks as follows,

```
 exchange(Input: string, Output: string, value: number): number {
        let inputRate = this.currencyStorage.getCurrencyRate(cnput);
        let outputputRate = this.currencyStorage.getCurrencyRate(Output);
        return value/ inputRate * outputputRate;
    }
```

How can i create a pipe out of this which can be used throughout the application to convert currency ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ts
@Pipe({name: 'currConvert'})
export class CurrConvertPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private currencyStorage:MyCurrencyStorage) {}

  transform(value: number, Input: string, Output: string): number {
    let inputRate = this.currencyStorage.getCurrencyRate(cnput);
    let outputputRate = this.currencyStorage.getCurrencyRate(Output);
    return value/ inputRate * outputputRate;
  }
}
```

register it with a modules `declarations` and use it like

```ts
{{123 | currConvert:456 /*input*/:789 /*output*/}}
```

Comment: <div class="price">{{123 | currConvert:EUR:USD}}</div> i did like this, it says undefined

Comment: I guess you mean ` 
<div class="price">{{123 | currConvert:'EUR':'USD'}}</div>` literal strings need quotes.

Comment: one question, will the pipe will work when we change the parameter without refreshing the page?

Comment: The pipe will be executed every time the value or a parameter changes - yes, without refreshing the page.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Should I hit Api to get currency rate inside pipe only? please suggest.

Comment: Hard to tell without more details. If the pipe returns a Promise because you are making async calls in the pipe, you need to add the async pipe to your bindings `123 | currConverter:456 | async`.