# How to Change the currency using Pipes on JSON data - ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-pipe

Hello I am trying to convert the Currency from USD to INR using Pipes.

This is my Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

declare var fx;

@Pipe({
  name: 'currency',
})

export class CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): any {
    fx.base = "USD";
    fx.rates = { "INR" : 70.204999,"USD" : 1 }

    let c = fx.convert(value, {from: "USD", to: "INR"})
    return c;
}
}
```

I am calling this pipe in my html as:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let data of mydata" style="padding: 1px;" (click)="getObject(data)">
   <ion-label>{{data.price | currency}}</ion-label>  
</ion-list>
```

My Price is not changing as the pipe is not working.

I am not good at pipes.your help is appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/42267400/5730444?

Comment: Angular has a native pipe named currency. Choose another name for yours. Also, we have no idea of what fx is, and it seems incorrect to mutate a global variable every time the pipe is executed.